Check package exists in cmake without reverting to the old policy settings
In my project, I use the Boost and CUDA libraries. Previously, I used find_package(Boost) and find_package(CUDA), followed by if(CUDA_FOUND) and if(Boost_FOUND) to check if those packages were available.
I recently upgraded to CMake 3.30. According to CMP0167 introduced in CMake 3.30 and CMP0146 from CMake 3.27, it is advised not to use find_package(Boost) and find_package(CUDA) directly, as CMake now handles these requirements differently.
How can I check if these requirements are satisfied without setting the policies to OLD?
Currently, I'm considering setting the policies to OLD to suppress warning messages:
if(POLICY CMP0146)
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0146 OLD)
endif()

However, I would like to know if there is a better way to check for the presence of these packages without reverting to the old policy settings.

"it is advised not to use find_package(Boost)" - that's not what I read. What I read is that the behaviour changes, but you still use find_package(Boost ...). Only CUDA has been morphed from a package into propert CMake language support, so it doesn't require find_package anymore?

When using find_package(Boost ...), a warning is displayed:
Policy CMP0167 is not set: The FindBoost module is removed.
When not using find_package(CUDA), if(CUDA_FOUND) returns false

Thanks @sehe, regarding find_package(Boost ...), I found out that I have to set the policy to avoid warning. It must be explicitly set, does not matter OLD or NEW.

Are you only using custom CUDA kernels (i.e. compiling .cu files) or also precompiled CUDA libraries (i.e. only compiling .c or .cpp files)? The CUDA language support in CMake only covers the first case. For the second case, you should use find_package(CUDAToolkit).

That new find method naturally has its own CUDAToolkit_FOUND. With the language support CMake should just error out if it can't find any CUDA compiler (doesn't have to come from CUDA Toolkit, could be clang or Nvidia HPC compiler as well).

@paleonix I use custom CUDA kernels.

What are you trying to do when there is no CUDA compiler? Just not compile that part of the project?

See CheckLanguage for avoiding enabling a language that is not supported on a particular system.

@paleonix the program should run either on GPU or on CPU. I intent to compile GPU version if CUDA is available, otherwise change settings to compile for CPU only program. check_language is a great idea. Thank you!
